# Proper syntax for Strings in Flash

Tags: flash, syntax

I know that I'm misusing a variable datatype. This is my code

```
itemList.dataProvider = new DataProvider();
for (var i:int=0; i<evt.data.length; i++)
{
    itemList.addItem({label:(evt.data[i].fname 
    + " " +      evt.data[i].lname), data:evt.data[i]});
}
```

In the for loop area where it's an integer, how can I change it into a string, cause my data to be retrieved is a string?
I'm sorry for the question, I'm just new with this language. By the way I'm using flash cs6 (air for android) and sqlite database.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain what's your problem please ?

Comment: I think the problem is the datatype that i used? How can i change it into a string?What is the proper syntax?

Comment: You can simply do : `String(your_var);` or usually `your_var.toString()`.

Comment: can you give me an example of using the string in a for loop?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. A for loop didn't need any special trick to use strings, it's like any other code ! Take a look here for [loops](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html).

Comment: With the code above can you alter it and change the datatype used?

Comment: Really, really I do NOT understand what you mean ! Change what to what ?  Your for loop looks fine !

Comment: The above code uses an int datatype, what i want is to change it into a string datatype. The problem is that i don't know the proper syntax for it. Hope you understand.thanks